# Disable reminders for events in the past in OWA?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2011, outlook-web-access

OWA (Outlook Web Access) is reminding me about all the meetings I have failed to dismiss, including many that are months and months old.  Dismiss all does not seem to permanently dismiss them.  How can I configure OWA to never alert me about events in the past?

Outlook for Mac 2011 also has this problem, and I was so annoyed by it I turned reminders off and use iCal instead.  I assumed it was a deficiency in this crappy version of Outlook.  But sometimes I have to use OWA on other machines and the same thing is happening...

Answer (score 1):

Ah, welcome to the weird world of Outlook and Exchange!

I'm afraid this is a common occurrence and it doesn't appear to have a complete fix.

The simplest thing to try is to create a new Calendar and copy all of your old calendar entries across in the hopes that it forces Exchange to reset the flags.

Comment: I cannot fathom why this has been a problem for so long.  Doesn't this also plague the Outlook engineers themselves?

Comment: Well it doesn't always happen and it doesn't happen enough to most people to make that big an issue of it. But yes it is strange. But that could be said of the whole of the Office suite! Each bit has some very strange things going on.